# Read every line and print Success or failure message

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a file `TBS.log` like this

```
SYSAUX      70.12
SYSTEM      81.74
UNDOTBS1    5.66
UNDOTBS2    1.93
UNDOTBS3    1.79
USERS       .16
```

I need to get the output as following. If 2nd column is greater than 70, then it should print Success Message, else it should print Failure Message
For example

```
SUCCESS: SYSAUX > 70%
FAILURE: UNDOTBS1 < 70%
```

It should read every line and give success or failure message

Comment: Hello Moses. What have you [tried so far](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/569717/edit)? Generally, people here are happy to help, but we're not a script-writing service.

Comment: Hi roaima, tried this for i in $(cat TBS.log|awk '{print $2}')
do
print
if cat TBS.log |grep -i ${i}|awk '{print $2}' > 70
then
cat TBS.log |grep -i ${i}
echo "SUCCESS"
else
cat TBS.log |grep -i ${i}
echo "FAILURE"
print
fi;
done

Comment: Moses, please put that into your post where everyone can easily see it. (Ideally make it seem like you had put that in originally. There's no need to write "edit" or "update" because there's a full edit history anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
    if ($2+0 > 70) 
      print "SUCCESS:", $1, "> 70%"; 
    else 
      print "FAILURE:", $1, "<= 70%";
}' TBS.log 
SUCCESS: SYSAUX > 70%
SUCCESS: SYSTEM > 70%
FAILURE: UNDOTBS1 <= 70%
FAILURE: UNDOTBS2 <= 70%
FAILURE: UNDOTBS3 <= 70%
FAILURE: USERS <= 70%
```

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver